# Autolaunched flow not invoking for multiple records

Tags: visual-workflow, automation, process-automation

I am using process builder to invoke the auto-launched flow whenever there is an change in the 'Status' field. This process builder and flow is working good for 2 or 3 records. But when I tried to create a 10 or 15 records to test the flow, its not working properly. As I tested, the process is correctly invoked the auto-launched flow, but the flow is not working.
[image]

Could you please point what I have done wrong?

Comment: , welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. What have you debugged and what exactly does it mean when you say "it's not working" - what do you expect to happen and what is not happening. You can [edit] your question to provide more specifics

Comment: You are doing a Get Records element within a loop which can lead to limits violations

Comment: @cropredy I tried to remove the flow and using invocable apex to avoid SOQL in loop, but still its not working

Comment: What does the debug log tell you?

Comment: Hi @cropredy, I have added one pause element in the starting of the flow. Because, when I checked the debug log, the changes are not committed in the DB for multiple records. After adding this pause, the changes are committed to DB and the conditions are working fine. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

After so many debug log and analysing I found some solution which is working good for me. In my scenario, when checking for 1 or 2 records changes, its working. But when I checked for more than 10 records the flow is not working properly. By checking the debug log, the recent changes are not committed in the DB. For this purpose, I just added the pause element at the beginning of the flow to commit all the changes to DB. For resume event, I have given 2 seconds and I have added no conditions for pause.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: using a Pause element starts a new transaction and resets limits. While this solution may get around your current issue; you may have some lurking, underlying inefficient trigger or automation.

Comment: @cropredy, how do I find this kind of thing in my code? Do I have any other solution to commit the changes at the end of the flow? Because, in my scenario one flow invokes another like wise doing some kind of work. If the there is some error happened in the 5th flow, all the 4 flows are rolled back. I don't want to happen like this. Is it there any solution for this?

Comment: You are asking a wider question here and should pose it as a separate question on this site.